# Incorperate slider value in label of slider

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, slider, label

Basically all I want to do is. Instead of having the value of the variable (`leftValue`) as part of a separate label. Have it as part of the label of the slider.

```
from tkinter import * 

master = Tk()
master.geometry("500x500")

leftValue = IntVar()
leftScale = Scale(master, from_=249, to=0, variable=leftValue, label="Characters in passwords will be:"+"_").pack()
leftLabel = Label(master, textvariable=leftValue).pack()

mainloop()
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You want something like [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/WobblyTrimNanotechnology#main.py). Read [AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7414759)

Comment: Yes that is exactly it. Thank you.